# Flutter: Provider not updating UI

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-provider

I am using Flutters `provider` library but I have problem getting it to update the UI.
I am performing a simple `HTTP POST` and want to **update my UI if an error occured**.

This is the logic in my **provider**:

```
class DeviceProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  // Enum with possible states: Initial, Loading, Error & Success
  APIState state = APIState.Initial;

  ...

  void sendConfig() async {
      try {
        http.Response postResponse = await http.post(...);

        if (postResponse.ok) {
          state = APIState.Success;
        } else {
          state = APIState.Error;
      }

      } on SocketException catch (e) {
        state = APIState.Error;
      }

      notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This my **UI**:

```dart
return ChangeNotifierProvider<DeviceProvider>(
      create: (_) => DeviceProvider(),
      child: Consumer<DeviceProvider>(
        builder: (_, model, __) {
          switch (model.state) {
            // Display error
            case  APIState.Error:
              return  Text('Error');
            // Ignore all other states
            case APIState.Loading:
            case APIState.Initial:
            case  APIState.Success:
              return const Visibility(
                child: Text("Gone"),
                visible: false,
              );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

My **main.dart** looks like this:

```
void main() => runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ...
          ChangeNotifierProvider<DeviceProvider>(create: (_) => DeviceProvider()),
        ],
        child: const MyApp(),
      ),
    );
```

Now, I know for a fact that the code is executed and that the state is indeed `Error`.

However, my error widget does not seem to be notified at all even tho I call `notifyListeners`.

What am I missing?

Comment: what's up with the two `ChangeNotifierProvider`?

Comment: try adding `notifyListeners()` after every state changes in your provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem arises when you use an other change notifier provider in your ui . when you trigger send config function you are triggering it with change notifier provider that you provided in your main.dart thats ok and all . but in your ui you attach a consumer to another provider in which you haven't triggered send config.

FIX : DON'T RETURN A ChangeNotifierProvider INSTEAD JUST RETURN A CONSUMER